# Git: How to diff two commits and apply that diff to a third one

Tags: git, diff

I have two commits, B and C. C is fixed version of B but not a successor as B was amended.
I want to apply this fix to another branch with last commit A.
How can I do that, ideally without intermediate patch file?

```
C
|  B
|/
.
.  A  <-- I want to apply diff from B to C here.
|/
```

I thought it could be `git cherry-pick --no-commit B C` but no.

Answer (score 0):

One approach would be to rebase onto `B`, then cherry-pick the resulting `C′` *(“C prime”)* onto `A`. `C′` has only the changes from `C` that aren't already in `B`.

Visually:

```
   C′
C  |
|  B
|/
.  
.  C″
.  |
.  A
|/
```

Commands:

```
$ git rebase --onto B C^ C
# Fix conflicts that may occur and commit.
$ git tag C-prime
$ git checkout A
$ git cherry-pick C-prime
# Again, fix conflicts because Git can be a little dumb sometimes (by design!)
```

*<sub>In the above, I'm just assuming **all** of the lettered identifiers are tags, not branches, so that my explanation doesn't have identifiers changing what commit they point to.  In reality, you likely won't need the `git tag …` command.</sub>*

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there is no such command out of the box. There are low-level commands like `git read-tree -m` but they do not provide any usable conflict resolution.

The most practical way is to make a fake commit from B to C and then cherry-pick it. These commands do it:

```
$ git checkout A
$ git cherry-pick --edit $(echo temporary | git commit-tree -p B C^{tree})
```

(the way to refer to tree object comes from [man gitrevisions](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitrevisions.html))