# git patch management workflow: porting changes from a rebased patch queue branch to a merged feature branch

Tags: git, git-merge, git-rebase

I'm working on upstreaming some code to qemu, which wants patches sent the the mailing list in small manageable chunks. I therefore have three branches in my git repository:

- `master`, tracks upstream.
- `feature`, has all my development history, including code that is not yet ready for upstreaming. This one is regularly merged with master, and published on github.
- `upstreaming`, the pending queue for patch submissions, which is regularly revised and rebased against master (and as a result, I don't publish this one, although per [What's the Git approach to publish a patch queue?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5016862/whats-the-git-approach-to-publish-a-patch-queue) perhaps I could do so with a suitable warning).

Each time I submit a version of the patch series to the mailing list, I get code review feedback and address that in the upstreaming branch (using `git rebase --interactive` and `git commit --amend`) before generating a new version of the patch series. This works reasonably well.

However, I'd also like to keep the `feature` branch up to date with these changes. Ideally, I'd like to record a single commit on `feature` that is equivalent to all the changes in the last respin of the patch series, however I have not found a clean way to do this.

If I merge from `upstreaming` into `feature`, then I have a ton of conflicts that I need to manually resolve each time, because the same files with almost (but not entirely) identical content appear to have been created independently; i.e. there is no common ancestor for a 3-way merge, and no merge history, so each subsequent merge of a new revision appears to be re-introducing a slightly different copy of the same file.

I think what I'd like to do is diff the vN and vN+1 of the `upstreaming` branch, and then apply that as a single patch to the feature branch. But (short of manual diff-and-patch) I haven't found anything in git to handle this.

Comment: Or use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34813665/2303202) to apply the diff

Comment: “I think what I'd like to do is diff the vN and vN+1 of the upstreaming branch, and then apply that as a single patch to the feature branch.”—I doubt that you can apply the output as a patch, but [git-range-diff(1)](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-range-diff) can compare two branches (seems to have been made exactly for comparing different patch series versions).  At the very least you can store the diffs in order to document the history of the patch series.

Answer (score 1):

There is one trick which I use, but it's not ideal. After you rebased `upstreaming`, you can `git merge --strategy-ours ..` its older head. Than it is remembered as forward-updated and can be merged.

Downsides are:

1. It looks ugly in history. All commits are mentioned both before and after rebase, sometimes mixed.
2. You should be careful to rebase only forward. For example if you `upstreaming` on some master's commit A1, and you rebase to later commit from the master A2 which is some grand-grand-child of A1. Then it's OK to merge-ours older `upstreaming`. But when you rebase it to some other branch B1, or to some earlier commit in master A0, then you must not merge older `upstreaming`, otherwise it will be considering some history before A1 as merged, but will not in fact have that changes.

Comment: Thanks! Actually, the [trick you linked in the comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34813665/2303202) seems like the best option for my current purpose. The ugly history is something I want to avoid on the upstreaming branch.